# Terms in math logic

Tags: logic

By definition term is every variable and every constant in formula, even function when its arguments are terms.

I have this two formulas

$(\forall x)(\exists y)((x<y)\wedge (\forall z)((\exists u)(y=z*u)\Rightarrow ((z=1)\vee (z=y))))$

terms are : x, y, z, 1, z · u

second formula

$(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(f(f(x+y))<z*z+1)$

terms are : x, y, x + y, f (x + y), f (f (x + y)), 1, z, z · z, z · z + 1,

My question is , why in the first formula "u" is not considered as term while its in binary operation (z*u) and in second formula z is considered as term while it is also in binary operation (z*z)

Comment: *Comment* : "$z∗+1$" seems not well-formed.

Comment: Why do you assert that $u$ in the 1st formula is not a term ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  because it is not in the list, which is presumably copied from the book.  I suspect it is a typo in the book and $u$ should be there.

Comment: It is from presentation from my school , its quite confusing me thats why i am asking , so u should be listed as term and its just typo?

Comment: I think so ... Apparently, also "$z∗+1$" is a typo; it must be  "$z∗1$" **or** "$z+1$".